# Loop to calculate organism growth

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a loop that calculates number of organisms over time, but I am stuck on how to make the loop update. Do I need to put something outside the for loop to update the total organisms?

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare variables for number of days passed and population 
        double days;
        double organisms;
        double increaseDaily;
        double total_organisms;

        //declare the constants to be used 
        const int interval = 1;
        const int start_days = 1;

        //try parse to get amount of starting organisms
        if (double.TryParse(organismTextBox.Text, out organisms))
        {
            //try parse to get the percent daily increase
            if (double.TryParse(dailyIncreaseTextBox.Text, out  increaseDaily))
            {
                //try parse to get the number of days passed
                if (double.TryParse(daysMultiplyTextBox.Text, out days))
                {

                    //for loop to count through the number of days
                    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i += interval)
                    {

                        //calculate the amount of organisms
                        total_organisms = (organisms * (increaseDaily / 100) + organisms);

                        //display the amount of organisms after an amount of time
                        listBox1.Items.Add("after " + i + " days, the amount of organisms is " + total_organisms);
                    }
```

Comment: If you replace all references to `total_organisms` with `organisms`, your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each loop, you are calculating the `total_organisms` as the sum of `organisms` plus some percent:

```
total_organisms = (organisms * (increaseDaily / 100) + organisms);
```

You are never changing the value of `organisms`, so `total_organisms` will be calculated as the same value each loop. You should just updated the value of `organisms` instead.

Also, you could reduce indentation in your code by changing each `if` statement to test for parse failure and bail out:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declare variables for number of days passed and population 
    double days;
    double organisms;
    double increaseDaily;

    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    //declare the constants to be used 
    const int interval = 1;
    const int start_days = 1;

    //try parse to get amount of starting organisms
    if (!double.TryParse(organismTextBox.Text, out organisms)) {
        errors.Add("Organisms must be a valid number");
    }
    //try parse to get the percent daily increase
    if (double.TryParse(dailyIncreaseTextBox.Text, out  increaseDaily)) {
        errors.Add("Daily increase must be a valid number");
    }
    //try parse to get the number of days passed
    if (double.TryParse(daysMultiplyTextBox.Text, out days)) {
        errors.Add("Number of days must be a valid number");
    }
    if (errors.Any()) {
        // Display errors to user here (depending on your UI)
        return;
    }
    //for loop to count through the number of days
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i += interval) {
        //calculate the amount of organisms
        organisms = (organisms * (increaseDaily / 100) + organisms);

        //display the amount of organisms after an amount of time
        listBox1.Items.Add(
            "after " + i + " days, the amount of organisms is " + organisms);
   }
}
```

Comment: Changing organisms worked! But the idea behind the if/else check is to make sure the data is good and return an error to the user if one field had inappropriate data in it. Can I use the way your code is laid out in that manner? I do like how much neater it looks.

Comment: You can put error handling code for the specific error in the places where I put the comment `//Report error`
If you want common code to handle errors then you can call a private method in those locations passing in any error-specific data if requried.

Comment: So could I write it so a message box pops up telling the user what they did wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my answer to show an example how you could collect and report all errors, but the best way to do that depends upon your UI and is a whole separate question/topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep adding to the total number of organisms:

```
total_organisms = total_organisms + (organisms * (increaseDaily / 100) + organisms);
```